# cambiar valores de un selector multiple y que solo afecte a su fila, en formulario dinamico

Tags: angularjs

Si suena un poco raro el titulo pero explico, tengo una columna que se llama "type_account" y otra "accuount", lo que pasa es que tengo que cargar cuentas de acuerdo al "type_account" que seleccione ahora la cuentas las llamo de distintos servicios, pero cual es el problema que cuando selecciono un "type_account" afecta todas las columnas que tengo en "accounts" cambian todas, necesito que solo afecte a su fila y solo se cambie el valor de su fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora en la imagen no se nota pero hay un boton que dice "agregar fila" agrega filas dinamicamente en el formulario.

el codigo de AngularJS (Angular 1):

```
var transactionCoverData = {};
var transactionDetailData = {};
$scope.userDropDown = false;
$scope.proveedorDropDown = false;
planaccountsfactory.getPlanAccounts().then(function (response) {
   $scope.planAccounts = response.data;
});
usersFactory.getUsers().then(function (response) {
    $scope.userDatos = response.data;
});
providersFactory.getProviders().then(function (response) {
    $scope.proveedorDatos = response.data;
});
$scope.subcuentasChange = function (type)
{
    console.log(type);
    if(type === 'usuario')
    {
        $scope.userDropDown = true;
        $scope.proveedorDropDown = false;
    }
    if(type === 'proveedor')
    {
        $scope.userDropDown = false;
        $scope.proveedorDropDown = true;
    }
};
//add row
$scope.detalleTransCover = {
    details: []
};
$scope.addDetail = function () {
    $scope.detalleTransCover.details.push({});
};
```

ahora el html es :

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in detalleTransCover.details track by $index">
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="detail.plan_account_id" ng-options="planAcoount.id as (planAcoount.tipo_cuenta + ' -- ' + planAcoount.descripcion) for planAcoount in planAccounts"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.glosa" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.debeDolar" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.haberDolar" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.debeBolivianos" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.haberBolivianos" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="detail.type_account" ng-change="subcuentasChange(detail.type_account)">
            <option value="usuario">EMPLEADO</option>
            <option value="proveedor">PROVEEDOR</option>
            <!--<option value="cliente">CLIENTE</option>
            <option value="activo">ACTIVO FIJO</option>-->
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" ng-show="proveedorDropDown" ng-model="detail.account_id" ng-options="proveedor.id as proveedor.razon_social for proveedor in proveedorDatos"></select>
        <select class="form-control" ng-show="userDropDown" ng-model="detail.account_id" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in userDatos"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás teniendo solo una variable en el $scope para manejar el estado de todos los combos de la vista. Deberías tener una variable por row para manejar cada combo.

En mi caso, lo haría de la siguiente manera:

**Change en Account_type**

```
ng-change="subcuentasChange(detail.type_account)"
```

a

```
ng-change="subcuentasChange(detail)"
```

**subcuentasChange**

```
$scope.subcuentasChange = function (detail)
{
    if(detail.type_account === 'usuario'){
        detail.proveedorDropDown= false;
    }else{
       detail.proveedorDropDown= true;
    }
};
```

**Selects**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-show="detail.proveedorDropDown" ng-model="detail.account_id" ng-options="proveedor.id as proveedor.razon_social for proveedor in proveedorDatos"></select>
<select class="form-control" ng-show="!detail.proveedorDropDown" ng-model="detail.account_id" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in userDatos"></select>
```

Espero que este acercamiento te sea de ayuda, cualquier cosa, no dudes en volver a preguntar. Saludos

Comment: gracias funciona perfectamente

Comment: Excelente! Saludos!